CKEditor5 - wrap entire editor html output in container element
I'm in a Vue 2 project, migrating away from Quill to Ckeditor5. In order to have backward compatibility, we need the Quill classes and styling to stay in place in all the placed where we display the html that the editor creates. The Quill css, however, breaks the CKEditor styles (specifically when it comes to sub-bullet points ul/li stuff).
The way I figured I'd combat this is by adding a container to all of the CKEditor output that I can have ignore the quill classes and use it's own styling.
something like:
<div class="ck-content ck-output-container">
   ...html output from editor
</div>

I've looked back over the docs and I'm not seeing something for this but I'm sure I'm missing it.
